# Getting error while taking typecasted number as index in array In Java

Tags: java, arrays, bounds

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String table[] = { " ", ".+@$", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" , "mno", "pqrs" , "tuv", "wxyz" };
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        int cn =(int)str.charAt(0);
        System.out.println(table[cn]);
    }
}
```

For input 12 this code is giving me Error as :-
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 49
at Main.main(Main.java:8)

can someone explain me why is this error coming and how to remove this error?

Comment: You are converting character to int , since the issue in this line int cn =(int)str.charAt(0);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.charAt()` method returns a character and when you parse it into `int`, it will give you the ascii value of that character.

For example, if you enter `12`, `str.charAt(0)` will return `'1'` and converting this character into `int` will give you 49 (ascii value for character 1) and index number 49 is out of bounds for the `table` array.

**Solution:**

You could convert the character returned by `.charAt()` method into `String` by passing the return value of `str.charAt(0)` as an argument to `String.valueOf()` and then parse that `String` into an `int` type by passing the return value of `String.valueOf()` as an argument to `Integer.parseInt()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String table[] = { " ", ".+@$", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" , "mno", "pqrs" , "tuv", "wxyz" };
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    
    int cn = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(0)));   // <-----
    
    System.out.println(table[cn]);
}
```

You could also use `+` operator to concatenate `str.charAt(0)` with an empty `String` and then pass the resulting `String` to `Integer.parseInt()`.

```
int cn = Integer.parseInt("" + str.charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 2):

As Yousaf mentioned you are typecasting character to int , hence you are getting the ascii value of the character and not the number . To make it work please update the this line of your code

```
int cn =(int)str.charAt(0);
```

to

```
int cn = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(0)));
```

Comment: Why are you using String.valueOf () ?

Comment: String.valueOf will give you the character as string , which you will parse to integer

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use this:

```
int cn = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine().charAt(0));
```

instead.